# Find the position of a value in a 3d array Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

So I have a 3d Array like `int[][][] test = new int[3][3][3]` the size of the 3d array can change to different sizes eg.: `int[][][] teste = new int[5][5][1]` or `int[][][] test = new int[2][3][1]` and so on. lets say im on position `test[2][0][1]` for the first example and I want to know a way where I can swap the current position with a variable position behind the current position eg.: I want to swap `test[2][0][1]` with the 3rd value which comes after that. So in that case it would be `test[2][1][1]`. How can I calculate that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume we have a 3d array `[3][3][3]`:

[image]

To solve this problem, let's imagine we are flattening the 3d array to a long list of all our elements then applying the needed shift to get the new index.

```
111, 112, 113, 121, 122, 123... 333
```

What will be the index of element `test[2][1][1]` in the long list?

That's quite easy to calculate:

```
1 + 1*3 + 2*(3*3) = 22
```

Why? to get to index 22 it had to pass all previous `3*3*2` elements in the first two tables, plus a row which is `1*3`, plus `1` column.

Having that done, we can now just add the shift, let's say it was `+3`. So its index is **25**.

Now we need to calculate what indices our element will have in our 3d array.

In which **table** will it be? well, he has passed `25/(3*3) = 2` tables, so table: **2**

In which **row** will our element be? he has passed `(25/3)` rows, BUT we need the row number in its table, so our element is in row number: `(25/3)%3 = 2`. Row: **2**.

In which **position in the row** will our element be? `25%(3) = 1`. Position: **1**

So the result: `test[2][2][1]`.

Now it's trivial to code:

```
public static Integer[] getIndices(int[][][] arr, int[] indices, int shift) {
    if (indices.length != 3) {
        return null;
    }

    int sum = indices[2] + indices[1] * arr[0][0].length + indices[0] * arr[0].length * arr[0][0].length;
    sum += shift;

    int i2 = (sum / (arr[0].length * arr[0][0].length));
    int i1 = (sum / (arr[0][0].length)) % arr[0].length;
    int i0 = sum % arr[0][0].length;

    return new Integer[]{i2, i1, i0};
}
```

---

Some output examples:

Input (sanity check):

```
int[][][] test = new int[3][3][3];
Integer[] indices = getIndices(test, new int[]{2, 1, 1}, 0);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indices));
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 1]
```

Input (from example above):

```
int[][][] test = new int[3][3][3];
Integer[] indices = getIndices(test, new int[]{2, 1, 1}, 3);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indices));
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 1]
```

Input:

```
int[][][] test = new int[5][8][2];
Integer[] indices = getIndices(test, new int[]{2, 5, 0}, 1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indices));
```

Output:

```
[2, 5, 1]
```

Input:

```
int[][][] test = new int[5][8][2];
Integer[] indices = getIndices(test, new int[]{2, 5, 0}, 5);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indices));
```

Output:

```
[2, 7, 1]
```

Comment: Wow thumps up for that very detailed answer. I was stucked for an hour at least but you saved me!

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what exactly you want to achieve for a single array. If you would want to swap values in [i][j][k] you can just use a loop.
Just pay attention because the j index is the index for your 2d space if applying the loop here you technically jump an whole array the switch nevertheless is simple:

If you want to switch a single value:

```
int[][][] test = new int [3][3][3];
int curr = test[2][0][1];
int behind = test[2][1][1];
test[2][1][1] = curr;
test[2][0][1] = behind;
```

now you effectively swapped the values at test[2][1][1] and test[2][0][1].

If you would like to do this for all values on your y axis you would write a loop with an iterator i for the corresponding axis.

Edit 1:
If you only know how many places you are after the current position but know your current position you can do the following:

```
int[][][] test = new int [3][3][3];
int curr = test[2][0][1];
int behind = test[2][0 + 3][1];
test[2][0 + 3][1] = curr;
test[2][0][1] = behind;
```

Just be aware of the length of your array.

Comment: I only know my current position and how many "places" behind my current position the to changing value is located e.g. 3. So I need to calculate the other position.

Comment: If you want to do that you can just use:
the same syntax but do:

    int[][][] test = new int [3][3][3];
    int curr = test[2][0][1];
    int behind = test[2][0 + 3][1];
    test[2][0 + 3][1] = curr;
    test[2][0][1] = behind;

Just be aware of the length of your array.

Comment: But thats my point I can't just go and type in +3 because of the length. I want something that calculates the positions so if k > 2 then I have to count j one up and so on. And I want a method that calculates the new position for pretty much every size 3d array